# make image from movie proportional when scaled?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

What would be the best way to take a screenshot with ffmeg ( say the first frame of movie ) and then
make a 200x200 image from it?

Im not sure what method to look for in docs or api to accomplish these tasks.

## EDIT #1

Seems that:

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -ss 3 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 600x600 output.png
```

Does convert to an image, but... this is not scaled (squased together)
what would be the correct way to have the image proportional?

Comment: The only thing I came across is to make a regular screenshot and crop it accordingly using ImageMagick's convert/mogrify.

Answer (score 1):

Copied and modified from elsewhere on Stackoverflow...

You want something like this: `ffmpeg -i` *video filename* `-vcodec` *video codec* `-vframes 1 -an -s 200x200 -f rawvideo output.jpg`